# How are Ansible group variable files parsed?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

In particular, I have a `group_vars/all.yml` file, with essentially the following contents:

```
my_foo: asdf
my_bar: '{{ my_foo }}'
```

If I later, while templating a file in a playbook, such as:

```
- name: template a file
  template:
    src: something.j2
    dest: '....'
```

And in that `something.j2` file, I use `{{ my_bar }}`, I somehow get `asdf`. **How?**

My prior understanding was that files such as `group_vars/all.yml` where essentially parsed as `parse_yaml(parse_and_evaluate_jinja2(contents_of_the_file))`. But if this were true, the line `my_bar: '{{ my_foo }}'` would not correctly evaluate: either we'd get an error, since `my_foo` is undefined *to Jinja*, or some default text, like `"undefined"`, or `''`. It's like the YAML was being parsed at the same time as the the Jinja2, which seems unlikely. Is that really what Ansible does? Or am I missing something else entirely?

(I couldn't find any exact documentation on how variable files are parsed in Ansibles docs, so if they exist, links are appreciated.)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*since `my_foo` is undefined to Jinja*". All variables "are defined to Jinja2" i.e. accessible from Jinja2. Actually, it's the only way you can access variable values in Ansible (that's why you need to use a Jinja2 expression `{{ ... }}` whenever you refer to a variable, with the exception on `when` conditionals in which Jinja2 templating is implicit).

Comment: To maintain a much simpler flow of variables I generally prefix the variables as per their location of definition. for example if the variable is in `group_vars` the prefix with `gv_`  .. if in playbook then `pl_` this helps understanding if someone is looking in template where the variable is actually coming from

Comment: @techraf That statement was made within the assumption that Ansible was doing `parse_yaml(parse_and_evaluate_jinja2(file_contents))`; in that worldview, `my_foo` is not yet defined. We can't use the definition on the preceeding line, as we've not parsed it out of the YAML yet. (Clearly, this assumption is invalid, as my testing demonstrated. I included it to show what my mental model of Ansible was, to provide context for my confusion. Konstantin below shows a different model that agrees with my test, and makes logical sense as to how it might be implemented.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My prior understanding was that files such as group_vars/all.yml where essentially parsed as parse_yaml(parse_and_evaluate_jinja2(contents_of_the_file))

Wrong. Ansible does all evaluation in runtime, for example:

You tell Ansible:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ my_bar }}"
```

So when Ansible is going to pass `msg` parameter to `debug` module, it will do:

1. What is the parameter?
2. The parameter is `{{ my_bar }}`. Oh, it's a template and there's variable `my_bar`.
3. What is the `my_bar`'s value?
4. The value is `{{ my_foo }}`. Oh, it's a template again, and there's variable `my_foo`.
5. What is the `my_foo`'s value?
6. The value is `asdf`. Good! Nothing more to template.
7. So, `my_bar`'s value is now `asdf`.
8. And parameter value is not `asdf`.
9. Let's print `asdf`.

By writing:

```
my_var: "{{ my_other_var }}"
```

you don't assign variables as in general programming, but write a simple template to calculate `my_var`'s value in any given time (runtime), and not in time of parsing.

Comment: Does this then imply that it isn't possible to use Jinja to template entire sections of the YAML? (i.e., like have a Jinja `{% if %}` that wraps a whole sub-dictionary, for example)

Comment: What do you mean by saying YAML? You can use `myvar: "{% if monday %}i_am_a_string{% else %}{'i_am_key':'i_am_value'}{% endif %}"` to get `myvar` as string on Mondays and as dictionary on other days.

Comment: I mean by having the value evaluate to YAML, e.g., `myvar: "{% if true %}[1, 2, 3]{% else %}…{% endif %}` (and having `{{ myvar }}` thus be a list, usable in a for loop somewhere.